# How to change the field precision step?

Tags: interface

I need to change the field precision input step (that one which is used when you press SHIFT and drag the field value) I want something like 0.001 instead of 0.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean *existing* fields as opposed to a Custom Property that you create (where you can control the step value)?

There appears to be nothing in "Edit :: Preferences :: Interface" that provides this ability.   If the number of your target fields is limited...

You could create such Custom Property (on a scene-common empty object or the object in question or ... here in World properties):

[image]

and then RMB:: Copy Field as New Driver,

[image]

and then RMB :: Paste Driver into a field you want to step at a finer rate.

[image]

But that's certainly of limited value, works with pure numeric fields (gets confusing for fields that want to deal in measurements, and is exhausting if you want such control over many, arbitrary fields.

example: [image]